# Audio and Zip file in PHP

Tags: php, audio, zip

I have three questions for you (working in PHP):
1. Is it possible to retrieve the time of MP3 audio located on server side?
2. Is it possible to join two or more MP3 audio in only one located on server side?
3. Is it possible to create a zip file by folder on server side and download automatically via web browser?

Thank you,

pasquy73

Comment: Google knows everything...

Comment: I'm just searching if all three tasks are possible. The 3. I think is ok. I need all three tasks

Answer (score 0):

3. Try it:

   $zipFile = tempnam('/tmp/', 'zip');
   $zip = new ZipArchive();
   $zip->open($zipFile, ZipArchive::CREATE);

   foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $fi) {
     if ($fi->isFile() && $fi->isReadable()) {
       $zip->addFile($fi->getPathname());
     }; // if
   }; // foreach

   $zip->close();
   header('Content-type: application/zip');
   echo file_get_contents($zipFile);
   unlinke($zipFile);